# Linking nouns and adjectives with -que

Tags: conjunction, enclitic

Elementary level here. Linking with -que: magna insula + magna paeninsula = magna insula magnaque paeninsula and cicada + magna lupa = cicada magnaque lupa (magna referring to lupa only). Are they correct? If in accusative, or in any other case, would it be the same?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your phrases are correct, and it works independent of the case. A similar example from Caesar's Bellum Civile ([1, 61](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/caesar/bc1.shtml#61)), using two plural accusatives:

> hic magnos equitatus magnaque auxilia exspectabant
> *here they expected large cavalry troops and large auxiliary troops*